# sort posts by date according to a drop down menu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

so i want to sort the posts according to a drop down menu where the user chooses which sorting to use either ASC (oldest) or DSCE (Newest) i tried a couple of approaches but they do not seem to work.

1. to pass the orderby=date & order=asc in the url using Square one media' code

   [the code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p917ngkd90s9v6j/WordPress%20Custom%20Sort%20Form.txt?dl=0)
2. to change wp_query parameters

   ```
   $args = array (
             'post_type'              => 'post',
             'post_status'            => 'publish',
     'paged'                  => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
      'cat'                    => 2,
      'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
         );
         $alchem_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $alchem_query->have_posts() ) :
          ?>
       <?php while ( $alchem_query->have_posts() ) : $alchem_query->the_post(); ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'article'.$alchem_blog_style ); ?>
       <?php endwhile;  ?>
       <?php endif;?>
       <?php wp_reset_postdata();
       }?>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to pass GET parameters to your query.

```
$args = array (
          'post_type'              => 'post',
          'post_status'            => 'publish',
  'paged'                  => (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
   'cat'                    => 2,
   'orderby' => (isset($_GET["orderby"])?$_GET["orderby"]:'date'),
     'order'   => (isset($_GET["order"])?$_GET["order"]:'ASC'),
      );
      $alchem_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     if ( $alchem_query->have_posts() ) :
       ?>
    <?php while ( $alchem_query->have_posts() ) : $alchem_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'article'.$alchem_blog_style ); ?>
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    }
?>
```